# App rejected because of screen resolutions

Tags: iphone, xcode

I published app to appstore and to my bad luck it was rejected.The reason is:
 - Was not optimized to support the device screen size and resolution;
Various visual elements were out of place in some views on iPad.

I do not understand what does this mean ?

Im running it in iphone 6.0,iphones5.0 simulators,iphone retina(3.5 inch),iphone retina(4 inch),ipad ,ipad retina.It is fine and I dont find any issues with resolution part.
I couldn't understand in which mode they did it.

How can I make my app to run well in both iPad and iPhone.Do I have to make any screen changes/resolutions.

Comment: This is off topic, but: Ask the reviewer for a screenshot of the issue. They will send you one and this will help you find the issue. And simulator != real device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're supporting the iPad, you have to design for the iPad. You can't just have your iPhone UI crammed into the top left corner; that is a worse user experience than if you don't support iPad (in that case the user sees the iPhone app, and can zoom it to fill the screen).

Either design for iPad (which will involve separate xibs / storyboards and some layout code) or mark your app as iPhone only. iPad users will still be able to download it.

Comment: I want to make it run on both ipad and iPhone.What should I do?What does this mean "Was not optimized to support the device screen size and/or resolution;".And sorry to ask but how can make the same app to run on both.Do I have to add any images which supports both?And if I test my app in ipad it shows me good user interface.

Comment: Make your app iPhone only. It then will run on the iPad in the correct way.

Comment: If the image in your question is from your iPad app, that is not a good user interface. What that sentence means is what I said - you're saying its an iPad app, but only had iPhone designs. In your target summary in Xcode, change "universal" to "iPhone".

Comment: no the image is from iPhone app.While designing I made it as iPhone app.Then why apple has tested for ipad also?

Comment: you made your app universal. If it would be iPhone only it would look like [this](http://jdevelopment.nl/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/m4n_on_ipad.png)

Comment: ok Thanks for the info. I just want to ask if I make my app to target iPhone only will the iPad users get same designs(user interface) like iPhone users?

Comment: Yes. It will run in a mini-iphone window which they can double the size on if they like. It's not great, it has the iphone keyboard, for example, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: ok.So I should design the whole xibs for all viewcontrollers and check in .m files whether its from ipad or iphone and change the UILabels,UITextFields sizes accordingly right.

Comment: Only if you're still making a universal app, I thought you were changing it to iPhone only?

Comment: No I want it to make it universal app now.

Comment: What Im thinking is to keep same xib for iphone and ipad and change it programatically in .m files which device is it whether ipad or iphone and change the dimensions accordingly?Is it Ok?

Comment: I'd do separate xibs, personally.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24615/discussion-between-sindhia-and-jrturton)

Comment: Just a last doubt as u have said to use separate xibs ,if i use so should I need to create separate ViewController with .m,.h .xib files targeted for ipad bcoz I have created separate .xib for ipad but in nib name I linked it to same viewcontroller and didnot create any separate .m and .h files.

Comment: if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
   {ViewController1 *viewController1=[ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1_ipad" bundle:nil];}else{ViewController1 *viewController1=[ViewController1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1_iphone" bundle:nil];}Currently I m doing like this .

Comment: Thank u ..Finally all my doubts are clear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give support iPad then you should make different xib for iPad also like this.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER alloc] initWithNibName:@"YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```